# Deadlock in C++/CLI Wrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I have a c++/cli wrapper class which grabs frames from a camera and sends them as events.

A WPF test application Starts the camera, and updates the images.
When I click `Stop`, it usually ends in a deadlock, on `m->streamThread->Join()`. I'm suspecting the problem has to do with the frame handling event in the WPF, rather than the wrapper code.

```
namespace WpfTestApp
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {

    private void OnFrameArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action a = delegate 
        {
            // this uses Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection
            // to copy the frame data to the image memory

            m_colorImage.UpdateImage(e.Image);
        };

        Dispatcher.Invoke(a);
    }

    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_camera.FrameArrived += m_frameHandler;
        m_camera.Start();
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        m_camera.FrameArrived -= m_frameHandler;
        m_camera.Stop();
    }
    }
}

// Camera.h
public ref class Camera
{
public:
    delegate void FrameArrivedHandler(Object^ sender, DGEventArgs^ e);        
    event FrameArrivedHandler^ FrameArrived;

    void Start();
    void Stop();

 private:
    void StreamThreadWorker();
    Thread^ m_streamThread;
    bool m_isStreaming;
 }

 // Camera.cpp
void Camera::Start() 
{
    if (m_isStreaming)
        return;

    m_isStreaming = true;

    m_streamThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Camera::StreamThreadWorker));
    m_streamThread->Start();
}

void Camera::Stop()
{
    if (!m_isStreaming)
        return;

    m_isStreaming = false;

    m_streamThread->Join(); // stuck here
}

void Camera::StreamThreadWorker()
{
    EventArgs^ eventArgs = gcnew EventArgs();

    while (m_isStreaming)
    {
        eventArgs->Image = Camera->GetImage();

        FrameArrived(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

likely what happens is: you click Stop, this gets handled in the WPF ui dispatcher thread. So the `Join` call is in the ui dispatcher thread. However this same thread is also responsible for drawing the frames (the invoked call to UpdateImage). As a result, the `StreamThreadWorker` is waiting on `FrameArrived` to finish, but that cannot finish because the thread is waiting for `Stop` to finish. There's your deadlock.

So in order to get the `StreamThreadWorker` to finish, it must not be blocked by `Stop`. An easy way to achive this is to stop the thread from within another thread:

```
void Camera::Stop()
{
  ...

  gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Camera::DoStopThread ) )->Start();
}

void Camera::DoStopThread()
{
  if( !m_streamThread.Join( 3000 ) )
    HandleThreadDidNotStopInTimeError(); //notify listeners there's a serious problem
  m_streamThread.Abort();
  m_streamThread = null;
  RaiseThreadStoppedEvent(); //notify listeners that the thread stopped
}
```

Comment: This seems logical. I will try it out. Why is the `Abort()` necessary if the thread terminates by itself?

Comment: if the `Join` does not finish in time (3 seconds in my example), the abort forces a stop. If the join call did succeed, abort has no effect